# jQuery cannot delete parent?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an element inside a div that is "draggable" jquery ui. And I am trying to remove that entire div. My element looks like

```
<div class="draggable">
    <img ...>
    <div class="delete">CLICK TO DELETE</div>
</div>
```

And it has a draggable event on it. And I want it so when you click on the delete button it deletes that entire div. But it does not seem to work. I've tried `$(this).parent/parents.remove` and neither of those work, they don't even return any kind of an object (`console.log($(this).parent());` returns []).

My delete function looks like

```
// Delete Image functionality
    $('.delete').click(function() {

        $this.parent().draggable('disable');

        // Post the DELETE request
        $.get('delete/', { d: '1' , id:photo }, function(data) {
            if (data == "true") {
                $(this).parent().remove();
            } else {
                alert("An error has been encountered, please try again later");
            }
        });
    });
```

Any idea what's up?

Comment: is there a reason you didn't define `$this`? you could use it directly inside of the $.get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, within the callback to `$.get`, `this` is set to the `jqXHR` instance. So you can do, for instance, `this.responseText`, should you wish.  Obviously it is no longer set to the element.

You need to give the element an alias that isn't overwritten:

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
    var clicked = this;
    $this.parent().draggable('disable');

    // Post the DELETE request
    $.get('delete/', {d:'1',id:photo}, function(data) {
        if(data == "true") {
            $(clicked).parent().remove();
        }else{
            alert("An error has been encountered, please try again later");
        }
    });
});
```

There are various other ways you could do it: the most efficient would be `var parent = $(this).parent().draggable('disable')` (presuming `draggable` is chainable, which it probably is). Another option would be to go by the event's `currentTarget` property:

```
$('.delete').click(function(event) {
    // ...
            $(e.currentTarget).parent().remove();
```

I think the version I've given is probably the clearest at showing *why* this didn't work for you, which is why I chose it.

Comment: @Steven lol you speak that i think right now ;) too late to think, maybe to late to ask on stackoverflow ;) lonesomeday and my (dknaack) answer are most the same, i think thats a sign that we both have to go to sleep. I would appreciate a upvote. And a accept for lonesomeday

Answer (score 0):

"this" inside of the inner function is different from "this" in the outer scope.  Try storing "this" in another variable, and using that variable within the outer function, i.e.:

```
// Delete Image functionality
    $('.delete').click(function() {

        $this.parent().draggable('disable');
        var that = $(this);

        // Post the DELETE request
        $.get('delete/', {d:'1',id:photo}, function(data) {
            if(data == "true") {
                that.parent().remove();
            }else{
                alert("An error has been encountered, please try again later");
            }
        });
    });
```